# Vuetify installation problem (These dependencies were not found: * Vuetify in ./src/main.js)

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I am trying to install and run a Vue project.

first I did:

```
npm install
```

then when I run

```
npm run dev
```

I am getting the following error

```
ERROR  Failed to compile with 2 errors                                                                                                                                                                                            

These dependencies were not found:

* Vuetify in ./src/main.js
* vue-events in ./src/main.js

To install them, you can run: npm install --save Vuetify vue-events
```

and when I run, **npm install --save Vuetify vue-events** I get the following

```
npm ERR! Linux 4.15.0-55-generic
npm ERR! argv "/usr/bin/node" "/usr/bin/npm" "install" "--save" "Vuetify" "vue-events"
npm ERR! node v8.10.0
npm ERR! npm  v3.5.2
npm ERR! code E404

npm ERR! 404 Not found : Vuetify
npm ERR! 404 
npm ERR! 404  'Vuetify' is not in the npm registry.
npm ERR! 404 Your package name is not valid, because 
npm ERR! 404  1. name can no longer contain capital letters
npm ERR! 404 
npm ERR! 404 Note that you can also install from a
npm ERR! 404 tarball, folder, http url, or git url.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK I found it,

I changed it the following line in main.js

```
import Vuetify from 'Vuetify';
```

to

```
import Vuetify from 'vuetify';
```

Answer (score 0):

first install vuetify

```
 npm install vuetify --save
```

Then import vuetify at ./src/main.js file

```
 import Vuetify from 'vuetify/lib'

 Vue.use(Vuetify)
```

Then install vue-events

```
   npm install vue-events
```

and import it like this

```
 import VueEvents from 'vue-events'
Vue.use(VueEvents)
```